# How to include "dev-master@dev" in a subdependency with composer?

Tags: composer-php

I have a problem I did not manage to solve.

Here is my example:

"A" requires :

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/form": "2.*",
        "massivescale/celery-php": "dev-master@dev"
    }
}
```

(because celery-php did not have any tags)

"B" requires "A".

```
{
    "requires": {
        "A": "@stable"
    }
}
```

If I do not add a "@dev" stability in "B" requires "A", I got an error because celery-php won't be fetched.
Id I do add a "@dev" stability in "B" requires "A@dev", "symfony/form" fetch the "dev" version.

The only solution I found is to require "massivescale/celery-php": "dev-master@dev" in "B", and that's awful because B does not need to know that A needs celery-php.

Another possible solution I did not search may be using a satis instance and/or a private fork to force version number, but it is a lot of maintenance for a small requirement.

Here is the link on the same question on Google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/composer-users/K6cMktI-fa4

Comment: Why do you force a stable version of A?

Comment: Because if I don't, the 2.*-dev branch of symfony/form is downloaded and that is not what I want.
The best option here I think would be an alias "dev-master#abcdef as 1.0.0" forced in "A" but as the alias refer to an unstable version, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, there is no real solution here.

The only solution found is to required dev dependencies in main package.

The real solution is to force your component to use stable version of their dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your root composer.json :

```
"prefer-stable" : true,
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

This will allow your second level deps to use dev packages.

More info on stability flag here : https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

And more details on stability-flags implementation : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/908

Hope it helps you.